# How data persistence work on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, persistence

I'm reading/writing data from/to a plist directly in the documents folder, so it is actually really stored in the device, so the data is changed and persist even if I quit and restart the app, this is by far my knowledge of how data persistence work on iOS, but the question is: what happen if I delete and reinstall the entire app? the data will be reset as the first state I suppose, how can you write something that persist even if you delete and reinstall the app? It is possible?

Comment: I think you mean "documents" folder, not "directory"?

Comment: yes documents folder, I've edited sorry